# Best practice to validate properties based on other properties

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

Imagine you have a class like :

```
public enum Kind { Kind1, Kind2 }
public class MyForm
{
    public string Kind { get; set; }
    public ACustomClass1 Custom1 { get; set; }
    public ACustomClass2 Custom2 { get; set; }
}
```

And you want to validate `Custom1` with `Custom1Validator` when `Kind == Kind1` (and `Custom2` with `Custom2Validator` when `Kind == Kind2`, obviously)

What is the best way to proceed with version 8.6.0 ?

At the moment, I've done like this (but I find it is awkward):

```
public class MyFormValidator : AbstractValidator<MyForm>
{
    public MyFormValidator (IStringLocalizer<Strings> localizer, Custom1Validator validator1, Custom2Validator validator2)
    {            
        //validate Kind and then, in function of Kind, use correct validator
        RuleFor(x => x).Custom((f, context) => {
            if (!Enum.TryParse<Kind>(f.Kind, out var kind))
            {
                context.AddFailure(localizer["Invalid Kind"]);
                return;
            }
            switch (kind)
            {
                case Kind.Kind1:
                    if (f.Custom1 == null)
                    {
                        context.AddFailure(localizer["Invalid Kind"]);
                    }
                    else if (! validator1.Validate(f.Custom1, out var firstError))
                    {
                        context.AddFailure(firstError);
                    }
                    break;
                case Kind.Kind2:
                    if (f.Custom2 == null)
                    {
                        context.AddFailure(localizer["Invalid Kind"]);
                    }
                    else if (!validator2.Validate(f.Custom2, out var firstError))
                    {
                        context.AddFailure(firstError);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Note that I am using asp.net core with dependency injection (this is why there is `IStringLocalizer` and I can not use `SetValidator` for Custom1 and Custom2)

What I'd like instead is something like

```
RuleFor(x => x.Kind).NotEmpty().IsEnumName(typeof(Kind)).withMessage(_ => localizer["Invalid Kind"]);
RuleFor(x => x.Custom1).NotEmptyWhen(f => f.Kind == Kind.Custom1.ToString()).withMessage(_ => localizer["Invalid Kind"])
RuleFor(x => x.Custom1).SetValidator(validator1); //would be executed only when custom1 is not null
```

//same for custom2

The problem is that I do not see how to do code the `NotEmptyWhen` method

Comment: Do you want your `Kind` property to be a `string` or a `Kind`? Right now it doesn't look like you're using the Enum for anything other than the awkward parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Restructure?**

By the looks of your posted code snippets, I presume that `MyForm` will never have a populated `Custom1` and `Custom2` property in the same request. So, instead of having a parent model that holds both payload *kinds*, I would encourage you to directly use the model that represents the payload being validated. Then you won't run into this nasty pattern of checking the *kind* wherever necessary.

One of your form endpoints accepts a `Custom1`, which has an associated `Custom1Validator`. Another one of your form endpoints accepts a `Custom2`, which has an associated `Custom2Validator`. They are decoupled. You can safely change one without affecting the other.

**Use Fluent Validation Conditions (When/Unless)**

If you're dead set on having *one* model responsible for representing the payload of multiple requests (please don't), you can use the `When()` method provided by the library. Take a look at their documentation on [conditional rules](https://fluentvalidation.net/start#conditions).

Comment: When/Unless was what I was searching for, thank you